# How to add data inside the package as environment variable in R

Tags: r, package, environment-variables

When I install my package or run it (library(...)) i would like to see it loading a particular data inside the package as environment variable for the execution. How can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Once your package is loaded with `library`, you can use `data` to load into your workspace the data that ships with the library. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Maybe it's a possible solution, but a colleague of mine used a function Internal.R to load the data on attach as GlobalEnv and I was wondering how to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.RData` file using `save` and put it in the /data/ folder of your package.

The in the DESCRIPTION file make sure it contains `LazyData: true` so that the data doesn;t take any space until you request it.

Everything is also detailed on
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html